# How to use GetItems in Powershell to retrieve list items

Tags: powershell

I'm having issues with this powershell script below.
It does work with SP 2007 but won't work with Sp 2010.
My goal as you can see is to filter the list returned using the field Date - 1.

But getting the error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>
> At C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\2\e70c0e06-6e66-4318-8480-952ccae0460e.ps1:31 char:20
>     + $col=$list.GetItems <<<< ($query)[0]
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetItems:String) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

```
function Daily()
{
    [System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.web")


    $site    =    new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://mysites/sites/Intranet/")                                                        
    #$web     =    $site.OpenWeb()                                                                                                
    $web=$site.rootWeb

    $list    =    $web.Lists["Communications"]                                                                              


    #$today = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $today = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")


    $caml = '<Where>
                 <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name="Date"/>
                  <Value Type="DateTime">
                  {0}
                  </Value>
                 </Eq>
               </Where>
             ' -f $today 


    $query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $query.Query=$caml
    $col=$list.GetItems($query)[0]

    $Results = @()
    foreach ($r in $col) { 


        $Title = "<b style='font-family:Calibri;'>" + $r.Title + "</b>"
        $Description = "<span style='font-family:Calibri;'>" + $r.Body + "</span>"
        $LinkToitemID = "http://Commus/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $r.ID
        $scommsLink = "<a href=$LinkToitemID style='font-family:Calibri;'> read </a>"
        $concResult = "" + "<br><br><b style='color:#0054A4;font-size:17px;font-weight:bold'>" + $Title + "</b><br/><br/>" + $Description + "<br>" + $scommsLink + "<br><hr>"

        $Results += $concResult


    }


    $web.Dispose()
    $site.Dispose()  


    write-host $Results 

}
```

Comment: What's that [0] after GetItems($query)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been fiddling around this a bit and found out that the described error occurs when list with the specified title does not exist.

Please, make sure that you have list with **title** "Communications" created on the `http://mysites/sites/Intranet/` site collection.

If the list exist, code works fine in my environment and line `$col=$list.GetItems($query)[0]` doesn't raise any errors. However, I anticipate that the `[0]` indexer is unwanted here, because you're getting the first item of the collection to **$col** variable, which obviously is a logical error.

Comment: Omlin the [0] was an error from my end.
You are right and thanks not good working too late.:(
I later fond out this morning i was using
                                                              $web=$site.rootWeb

thinking the site was after intranet wheareas  the intranet was the root site and then communications was the subsite and then a list called communications.:(

One more questions though i have a field called Body and its a rich textbut i noticed it doesn't return any value.The only fields that i get values from is if its a "single line of text"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your caml query may also need to be surrounded with

`<query>
...
<query>`